# if (op['insertOne']) {TypeError: Cannot read properties of null (reading 'insertOne')

Tags: javascript

Although I was doing insertion to Mongodb, the question is unrelated. I have the following code; it produces the TypeError; I checked the `state.id.slice`; it's the `string` type and does have a few objects that fulfill the condition, and if I change the condition to `if (1 === 1){...}`, the following code works without error. Where is the problem?

```
import States from "./models/states.js";

import { connectToDB } from "./utils/database.js";

export default async function updateStates(states) {
  await connectToDB();
  const bulkwrite = await states.map((state) => {
    if (state.id.slice(0, 3) == "FBL") {
      return {
        updateMany: {
          filter: { id: state.id },
          update: state,
          upsert: true,
        },
      };
    }
    return null;
  });

  const res = await States.bulkWrite(bulkwrite);
}
```

The complete error:

```
/Users/tung/project/sk/mongo_db/node_modules/mongoose/lib/helpers/model/castBulkWrite.js:24
  if (op['insertOne']) {
        ^

TypeError: Cannot read properties of null (reading 'insertOne')
    at castBulkWrite (/Users/tung/project/sk/mongo_db/node_modules/mongoose/lib/helpers/model/castBulkWrite.js:24:9)
    at /Users/tung/project/sk/mongo_db/node_modules/mongoose/lib/model.js:3366:37
    at Array.map (<anonymous>)
    at Function.bulkWrite (/Users/tung/project/sk/mongo_db/node_modules/mongoose/lib/model.js:3366:27)
    at updateStates (file:///Users/tung/project/sk/mongo_db/States.js:20:28)
    at process.processTicksAndRejections (node:internal/process/task_queues:95:5)
    at async Timeout.stateUpdate [as _onTimeout] (file:///Users/tung/project/sk/mongo_db/app.js:99:3)
```

Comment: What is the type-error you get?

Comment: I added to the content; thank you. @BadPiggie

Comment: can you show me what you get when u `console.log(state.id)`

Comment: I found out the problem, please check, thank you! @BadPiggie

Answer (score 0):

I found out the problem, since I was using `if (state.id.slice(0, 3) == "FBL")` in side `states.map`, some `null` will add into the return array if some elements failed the condition, so when `States.bulkWrite(bulkwrite)` send some null item, the error is triggered, so I use `flatMap` to fix the problem, not sure if it's the best way to do it.

```
export default async function updateStates(states) {
  await connectToDB();
  const bulkwrite = states.flatMap(( state ) =>

    state["id"].slice(0, 3) === "FBL"
      ? [{
          updateMany: {
            filter: { id: state.id },
            update: state,
            upsert: true,
          },
        }]
      : []
  );
  const res = await States.bulkWrite(bulkwrite);
}
```